# Automatic space after fgets' result?

Tags: php, space, fgets

it seems as if fgets puts a space after everything it returns.
Here's some example code:

```
<?php
Echo "Opening " . $_SERVER{'DOCUMENT_ROOT'} . "/file.txt" . "...<br>";
$FileHandle = @Fopen($_SERVER{'DOCUMENT_ROOT'} . "/file.txt", "r");
If ($FileHandle){
    Echo "File opened:<br><br>";
    While (!Feof($FileHandle)){
        $Line = Fgets($FileHandle);
        Echo $Line . "word<br>"; //Should be LINECONTENTSword, no space.
    }
    Fclose($FileHandle);
}
?>
```

which returns

```
Opening /var/www/vhosts/cqe.me/httpdocs/file.txt...
File opened:

First line word
Second line word
3rd line word
Another line of text word
Blablablaword
```

Why is there a space between the line's content and "word"?
And why is this space not there at the end of the file (Blablablaword)?

Could you please tell me how to get rid of this space?
Thanks a lot :-)!

Comment: it is customary to accept a solution (a checkbox, i believe) if it works for you, so that others like myself will know if you no longer need more elaboration.

Comment: I thought the green check would suffice? Excuse me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[fgets()](http://php.net/fgets) returns a line **and** the newline character (`\n`). This would then, as all other whitespaces, be rendered as a space in HTML.

To remove the trailing newline, use

```
$line = rtrim($line, "\r\n");
// Trims \r, \n and \r\n, which are all considered
// newlines on different platforms
```

Answer (score 7):

I believe fgets returns the end of line character (\n) also, and this is rendered as a space in html.

If you want to remove all trailing space from the line, you could use [rtrim](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php)